# How to trigger function when cell is edited to certain text in google sheet app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a beginner and didn't know much about app script and I'm looking forward to learn app script.
I'm trying to run this function when the cell is equal to 'TRUE' and didn't want to use a button to trigger this function

The main issue is I'm trying to share the form using &rm=minimal URL but the button seems didn't work, [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17hyNNI2mEiWjtUpTf1G1JJvtp3UcGJmzMv4n205nAKo/edit?**&rm=minimal**#gid=0](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17hyNNI2mEiWjtUpTf1G1JJvtp3UcGJmzMv4n205nAKo/edit?&rm=minimal#gid=0)

Second, I tried to use HTML submit button and still didn't work too.
Then now needed to try trigger this function when cell is equal to
. I try to learn onEdit function but kind of loss here... and this is my function

```
function SubmitData() {
  
  var ss          = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS      = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); 
  var datasheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("156va3bF91wJVYu7y7JQ_NrFEoO1GferSkOdP5P8Wveg").getSheetByName("Data Entered");

  var values      = [[formSS.getRange("E4").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("C4").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("C50").getValue(),
                      formSS.getRange("C51").getValue()]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(values);
      
  formSS.getRange('E4').clearContent();
  formSS.getRange('C4').clearContent(); 
  formSS.getRange('C50:C51').clearContent();

}
```

Example: I want to add this

```
function onEdit(e){

//don't know how to point the cell here

  if('B52' == 'TRUE'){  //if cell equal to text
  SubmitData() //run the function and needed to set the value to 'FALSE' again

 }
}
```

Hopefully, someone could help me out here...

Comment: You say `I'm trying to run this function when the cell is equal to 'TRUE'`  what cell?

Comment: Your spreadsheet access is not public.

Comment: should be any cell that I'm pointing. An example 'B52'

Comment: @MiMi try again.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the value is "TRUE" or not when the cell has changed (without pushing another button)?

onEdit()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

May be something you are looking for.